# Perform simple calculations in php on output from wordpress mysql table

Tags: php

I am using the following code for the output of mysql table value:

```html
echo $result[0]->column1;
```

Now I want to perform some simple maths by using 2 columns of the table. I have tried the following code but it is not working:

```html
echo $result[0]->(column1 / column2 * 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`column1` and `column2` are the field names (properties of an object) of `$result[0]` so what you would like to do is:

```php
echo $result[0]->column1 / $result[0]->column2 * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get both values separately and typecast the to int to be sure the calculation can be done correctly.

This should work:

```php
echo (int)$result[0]->column1 / (int)$result[0]->column2 * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

column1, column2 aren't variable. Yeah, they're names of object's member property.
They are not allowed math operating. Is it clear?
Yes, if you want do as following.

> eg:`echo ($result[0]->column1/$result[0]->column2)*100`